# Docker - Ok to delete data loop file?

Tags: centos, docker

M'm having an issue with a growing data file that is getting too large in my centos7 server. Links to similar issues i've seen: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3182

This link suggests stopping docker, deleting the data file and turning back on docker: [Why is docker image eating up my disk space that is not used by docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853571/why-is-docker-image-eating-up-my-disk-space-that-is-not-used-by-docker)

Will deleting the data loop file destroy my existing container data? Or images? What does this file do?

I can also add more diskspace to this server, but it seems like padding the issue instead of solving whats going on:

Docker Version:
Client version: 1.4.1
Client API version: 1.16
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 5bc2ff8
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.4.1
Server API version: 1.16
Go version (server): go1.3.3

Comment: you can manually remove the images with the docker rmi blabla command and the container with the docker rm blabla

I know that is not safe etc but most of the time i just use docker rm $(docker ps -aq) when the container that I want to keep are running
For the images that actually doesn't work like that but when I'm in trouble I just eliminate all and re download them

Comment: @luca: But removing containers and images won't release the disk space. That's the whole issue here.

Comment: I've got same question