# Can you please suggest on best ways to cleanup docker containers

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker. Would like to  know about the ideal ways to cleanup docker containers.

To clean up containers I'm simply stopping container and just removing it using `docker rm` command.

But it seems like docker is eating hard disk space. I been through
[Why is docker image eating up my disk space that is not used by docker article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853571/why-is-docker-image-eating-up-my-disk-space-that-is-not-used-by-docker). But is there any other way to do the same. Please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

It's worth looking at the [docker-gc](https://github.com/spotify/docker-gc) project that Spotify came up with to address this problem.

docker-gc essentially just automates running of the commands suggested in the other answers, but also has support for whitelisting images etc.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Will check.

Answer (score 1):

Stop all the containers (`docker stop <containerId>`) you don't need anymore and run those two commands:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

The **first** command will **delete all inactive** containers (the others will pop up errors, but they can be ignored).

The **second** command removes all images that are **not used by any container** (also the non actives).

*Note*: The next time you start a container you have to download all the layers again.

---

As [Mark O'Connor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256618/mark-oconnor) pointed out there is also the `-v` option to remove associated volumes. Make sure you don't loose any important data with that!

```
docker rm -v $(docker ps -a -q)
```

From the [Docker rm docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/rm/):

```
    -f, --force=false      Force the removal of a running container (uses SIGKILL)
    -l, --link=false       Remove the specified link
    -v, --volumes=false    Remove the volumes associated with the container
```

Comment: And the "-v" option to the docker rm command. Removes any volumes associated with containers.

Answer (score 0):

1. List running images

   `docker ps`
2. Stop them

   `docker stop [container name or id]`
3. List stopped

   `docker ps -a`
4. Remove stopped

   `docker rm [container name or id]`
5. List your images

   `docker images`
6. Remove images

   `docker rmi [image name or id]`

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is run a container once, and delete it when done, invoke it with the `--rm` option. The container will be automatically removed after exit.

```
docker run --rm ubuntu:14.04 cat /etc/lsb-release
```

If you monitor `docker ps -a` you will see the container being launched and then removed.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to Cleanup docker container and especially in a PROD environment

1: `docker ps -a`

2: Clean up things that you are not used by any resource with `docker system prune -a`

3: Last remove anything that needs to be removed with 
**PS : Be careful** as anything that will be removed there is no way back!
`docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) 
docker rmi $(docker images -q)`