# How to clear used space after docker?

Tags: docker

Recently I pulled and ran an image that in total used up 45GB of memory on my host drive. After I've deleted both container and image I still have my drive full. How can I clean up the space used?

Comment: @FirstOne yes! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though answer privided by Ömer Sezer can rely to some cases but for mine [this was the correct thing to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73137144/20990693). Thanks to @FirstOne for providing the thread where I found the answer.

Comment: Minor quibble: Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, and does not have "threads". (We're prickly about the terminology sometimes, because we try to keep focus on being [a long-tail FAQ](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) with curated, canonical questions and answers consistently written in an encyclopedic style; discussion forums usually don't come with that set of constraints). Similarly -- and for reasons also explained behind that link -- when multiple questions cover the same ground, we try to keep only one.