# Where is docker image location in Windows 10?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I'm using the Windows 10 Home operating system.
I have installed Docker toolbox.

I have created a docker image of my .net core application by using following command.

```
$  docker build -t helloWorld:core .
```

Now I want to ship this image, to another machine. But I am not getting the image file.

Can someone please tell me, where my image will get saved? Or is there any way, to specify docker an image path in docker build command.

Comment: Have you checked : C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks\MobyLinuxVM.vhdx? I find mine there. Thank you for asking the question. @purnima-naik

Comment: See also [Is there a way to see container disk usage on Docker for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55875910/is-there-a-way-to-see-container-disk-usage-on-docker-for-windows)

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed in a million of years that the biggest problem in my project would be to find out where the image is stored.

Comment: YES late! I agree fully. Still have not found my built images. Frustrating as hell!!!

Answer (score 176):

All the answers have been outdated or incorrect for me, I found it in `%localappdata%\Docker\wsl`

Comment: And this should be accepted answer. ext4.vhdx file is located in: %AppData%\Local\Docker\wsl\data

Comment: I dont inderstand it. I expect docker file or something like json or yml file. How can I change config values e.g. for db connection?

Comment: %AppData%\Local\... does not exist found it on %LocalAppData%\Docker\wsl

Comment: This is the right location, how to access it inside of this? The disk image isn't initialized : (

Comment: Oh my God whole internet is full of people searching where is docker image file. What a pathetic design and support by Docker creators. Finally I found correct answer here. Many thanks.

Comment: C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Local\Docker

Comment: There is something wrong here. I DO see ext4.vhdx in that location with the correct time stamp. But it is not the name I gave it and the size is 2.5 GB. docker images says its size is just under 500 MB. What is missing here?

Comment: My ext4.vhdx was at ~60 GB despite having pruned everything using Docker and I used `wsl --shutdown` and `wsl --unregister docker-desktop-data` which removed the virtual drive. Starting Docker Desktop created a fresh one, and I changed the default WSL distro back using `wsl --setdefault docker-desktop-data`.

Comment: Mind that you can change the location manually even through the Docker Desktop UI Settings page. Which also moves all previously files stored at the original location.

Answer (score 88):

The answers are really confusing because there is more than one way to run Docker in Windows. The newest way is with Windows 10 Home May 2020 Update. It will use the new version of Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2). This answer is about this configuration.

After [activating WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10), you'll install [Docker Desktop](https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows). Docker Desktop is a client that'll connect to the host inside the WSL.

The image directory is somewhat inconsistent. If you run `docker info` in your host machine or inside WSL it will give you the path `Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker` which doesn't exist:

```
$ ls /var/lib/docker
ls: cannot access '/var/lib/docker': No such file or directory
```

You'll find the images in

```
/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/
```

Or in this Windows Explorer path:

```
\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\mnt\wsl\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\image
```

If you are using Windows 10 non-Home versions, it may work differently. Take a look at the other answers. Since I don't have access to this OS, I won't try to answer.

Comment: I think this is the only correct answer for WSL2. Certainly is on my system.

Comment: Now the path \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\mnt\wsl\docker-desktop-data\data\ is empty for me, although `docker info` says I have 4 images.

Comment: @AlexandrZarubkin The correct path in my case was: `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\image` and/or `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\overlay2` (depending on what you're looking for)

Comment: I think the latest is `\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\image\overlay2\imagedb\content\sha256` now..

Answer (score 59):

On Windows 10, right click on the docker icon in the system tray (right hand side of task bar) and choose Settings...
In the Advanced pane, you'll see something like:

[image]

Comment: Could get this path location in the Advanced Settings menu, but this path doesn't exist in my file system despite have set to show hidden and system files & folders!

Comment: Maybe this file location is intended only for windows' images while I have only linux images pulled in my local docker platform!

Comment: The advanced tab doesn't seem to be available in the latest version these days.

Comment: @kmarabet try `Public Documents` instead of `Documents` in the path

Comment: @shwz you're right there's a hyper-v there... but it's admin accessible only... bummer

Comment: @JustinHelgerson  You get advanced option only when docker uses Linux containers. For Windows container you can go to Docker Settings --> Daemon Tab on left --> Select Advance toggle button  and update the JSON file with   "data-root" : "E:\\DockerContainers".

Comment: I'm using latest free version Docker on Windows 10 (linux containers) and I'm able to change the images storage location by specifying `Disk image location` located in `Advanced` tab in Docker Settings. Just updated mine and Docker required a restart VOILA it doesn't eat up my SSD spaces C drive anymore.

Comment: @Matt I am using Docker v19.03.8 on Windows 10 and Windows Containers, and there is no Daemon tab on the left. There is just General, Resources, Docker Engine and Command Line.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisBeauchamp, Not sure about the specific version, do you see tabs mentioned like in the article https://medium.com/@matt.thankachan/docker-how-to-change-drive-letters-for-docker-container-images-86a7a8f74b7d . Also see if you can change it via the json file

Comment: For v19.03.8, check the tab **Docker Engine**

Comment: Seems like they've moved this elsewhere.

Answer (score 56):

1. By using the `docker info` command.
2. In the result - check for **Docker Root Dir**

This folder will conatins images, containers, ...

[image]

Comment: On my Windows 10 machine, I get this path "Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker", which doesn't exists on my machine.

Comment: Are you running Docker or Docker Toolbox? By the logs, it seems that you are running Docker-Toolbox, which runs the linux VM for docker-machine.
In this case - conect to docker-machine, and go to this specified folder

Comment: My root dir is /var/lib/docker. Can I navigate to that folder via explorer?

Comment: @MikeCasas Maybe you are using Linux containers, just right click the docker icon, choose `Switch to Windows containers...`

Comment: @TonyChou, no, I want Linux continer. Just wondering if I could navigate to the folder.

Comment: Why is it impossible to get good information about docker?? This is so frustrating! Like the people above, I am running linux containers on a Windows 10 machine and I am unable to figure out what magical location docker stores the containers in.

Comment: If you have linux containers on a Windows 10 machine, containers are stored in the MobyLinuxVM.vhdx file. You can't mount or explore that file AFAIK, but you can still list the containers inside that machine using this 'blue pill' trick https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/11/ssh-into-docker-vm-windows/ by default containers are stored in the linux path /var/lib/docker in that virtual machine (you can confirm that linux path from a `docker info` command)

Comment: i am not able to find path "Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker" on my machine

Comment: First, check if you are running windows containers since this just work for them (windows containers are not the same to run docker in window ok?). In case you are running Linux containers, images are in WSL, thus you must check out if they are in the virtual file located in %AppData%\Local\Docker\wsl\data\

Comment: By me: Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker. But with no indication of driver?? So I installed docker on my E drive. Not my windows disk(C). So I looked in E for var. But it doesn't has a lib in var?? very very confusing.

Comment: /var/lib/docker for me

Answer (score 39):

If you are using docker on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2), you can access the images via hidden share:

`\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\overlay2`

The volums are also there at:

`\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes`

The docker version is `20.10.7`

[image]

If you want to go deeper,  the `docker-desktop-data` is actually located in a file at your `AppData\Local` as a `vhdx` ( virtual machine disk) `C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\data\ext4.vhdx`

You can terminate docker process and open `ext4.vhdx` file ( with 7zip for example), and there you can see `version-pack-data\community\docker` in this file.

Comment: Thanks, I could see these paths on my machine. But where are mounted on windows drive.  Like in the screen shot (which was from a previous version of docker) we could change location to another drive via GUI even for linux container, but now we can't. Not sure to where \\wsl$ is mounted in windows. I want to change it to D drive as C is all full.

Comment: thanks for giving the clue, however i found it in a slightly different path:

\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\overlay2

Comment: In my case I found volumes here: \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes

Answer (score 23):

If you are on windows 10 and running windows containers

[image: docker running windows containers]

In the above image, docker is running windows containers. So its showing switch to linux containers.

First run `docker info` command (more specific `docker info --format “{{json .DockerRootDir}}”`).

You should see root dir as

Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\Docker

Now run a command to pull an image like

```
docker pull hello-world
```

After it pulls the image, you can look into the docker root dir.

Notice the current modified date time. In one of the folders you can see the sha of the layers.

[image: Docker location on windows]

Finally, you also have to take a look into the following folder, if you want to know where the images are downloaded. The two folders above and below are

- C:\ProgramData\Docker\image\windowsfilter
- C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter

[image: Docker location]

Now for linux images.

If your docker is running windows containers, and then if you try to fetch a linux based container such as nginx, like so

```
docker pull nginx:latest
```

you will get a message as follows.

```
latest: Pulling from library/nginx
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.18363 in the manifest list entries
```

So switch to linux contaners. See the very first image.

Once the docker for linux is running, run the command again.

```
docker pull nginx:latest
```

You can see that image is downloading.

Now where is this image downloaded on your hard disk? docker info command may not help much in this case.

So start again. Click Settings and now "Switch to Windows Containers..."

[image: Settings On Docker Desktop for linux containers]

And now see the path.

[image: Settings Page on docker desktop showing the path]

On my machine, it's `C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\vm-data`

[image: LinuxImages location]

Note the date modified column. Notice and observe that after you pull or remove a linux based image.

That's a diskspace reserved for linux env, so you will not be able to browse further down to see where the image is.

but if you have to, then launch a linux based VM, install docker and explore the path
/var/lib/docker/

Sometimes you may encounter permission issues. If so see [this](https://superuser.com/a/221094/674525) and [this](https://superuser.com/a/221029/674525)

Comment: THanks, this is helpful but i need little more help further from here. I do see the Dockerdesktop for 7gb data size. Could you explain or share me links on how to clean up those or see further inside whats holding that 7gb? Also, my docker settings is currently set to linux containers it seems, as i see an option to switch to windows containers only. Although, i do not see the images of linux containers in /programData/Docker/$$$ path

Comment: What does it mean "Click Settings *and not* "Switch to Windows Containers...""?   BTW on my system is the same as in your answer (because it turned out I'm using WSL1), but I do not  need to switch to windows containers anyway, to view it.

Answer (score 21):

When you have **Windows Containers** activated, your images are stored by default in `C:\ProgramData\Docker\`

To change this, you can edit the `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json` and add a new `"graph"` key with the new path... (notice that every backslash is escaped with another backslash)

Example:

```json
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": false,
  "graph": "D:\\ProgramData\\Docker"
}
```

After that, you need to **restart Docker service** and you can verify your changes using `docker info` command and look at `Docker Root Dir` entry.

Comment: Javier is right. You get advanced option only when docker uses Linux containers. Also i believe we use  "data-root" for providing the image locations

Comment: I see that there is a setting in the Docker context menu - `switch to Windows Containers`. I thought that this would mean that the 'base container' would be a Windows OS instead of a Linux OS. But this is not the case? I would like to be able to access the virtual HD in the Hyper V virtual hard disks. But this seems impractical..

Comment: for me: C:\Users\savantKingShirt\.docker. Holy holy!! really docker is putting everywhere files on my disks. holy crap!! and my vhdx file is already 2GB!!

Answer (score 16):

I was not able to find the location of a WSL based Docker installation. But there is a simple way with docker commands itself to get the image!

```
docker image save myimagename -o myimagename.tar
```

This creates an archive file you can browse through with 7zip or a similar program.

Comment: thanks, that helped a lot instead of finding files.

Comment: This honestly sounds like the answer that is also future-proof across potential changes to the internal storage. I know it's not strictly the requested answer but the one I will definitely be using to get it into distributable form.

Answer (score 16):

In Recent Docker Desktop - which now uses WSL, the docker image location in Windows 10 is changed -

`(last tested with Docker Desktop Community version 2.3.0.3)`

First use Run - and type `\\wsl$`

This will open the file explorer, and display the folders as below -

1. `docker-desktop`
2. `docker-desktop-data`

Browse the directories to see the required files.

**Note**: Make sure docker desktop is running before using `\\wsl$` command

[image]

Answer (score 11):

As of today 29 Aug 2022:

Here:

```
%localappdata%\Docker\wsl
```

And here:

```
C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\vm-data
```

And in older days it was here:

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks
```

So yes. ProgramData, AppData, Documents etc etc they can store just anywhere on your disk. Docker is perfectly unorganized product. Wastes lots and lots of time of developers figuring out little little things.

Answer (score 9):

mine can be found in "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks"

Answer (score 8):

you can use below command to export your image and can copy same to linux / another machine 
docker export [OPTIONS] CONTAINER

example:

```
docker export --output="latest.tar" red_panda
```

Answer (score 8):

To to ship this image, to another machine :

```
docker ps -a  
#or docker container ls -a
docker commit <container-id> mynewimage
#start here if you never started your image 
#(ex: if just created using docker build -t helloWorld:core .)
docker image ls
docker save mynewimage > /tmp/mynewimage.tar
```

On the other machine:

```
docker load < /tmp/mynewimage.tar
docker images
```

As explained in comments above, when working on windows with linux containers, containers resides within the docker disk image located at DockerDesktop/settings/advanced/DiskImageLocation

see [here](https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/1512-export-and-import-a-docker-image-between-nodes)

Answer (score 5):

The docker desktop for windows 10 has been moved here:

c:/users/`<user>`/AppData/Roaming/Docker/settings.json

%APPDATA%\Docker\settings.json

Answer (score 3):

For me, running on Window 10 Professional version 20H2 with Docker Desktop 4.5.1 (74721), the location of images seems to be under my user directory as the following picture.

[image]

Comment: Ditto.  It can be found at Docker Desktop->Settings->Resources->Advanced

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why are you trying to reach the image, but you can create a backup file from it just using docker command and load it afterwards where you wish. Example:

```
$ docker save -o ubuntu.tar ubuntu:lucid ubuntu:saucy
```

It will save a tar file in your Windows home directory. To load it:

```
$ docker load --input ubuntu.tar
```

Comment: Because I want to upload the image to an AWS instance.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the containers were under [image: container location in Docker Desktop] when using Docker desktop on Windows with WSL2.

Comment: Can you please add the path in string format as well maybe?

Comment: \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\containers

Comment: This is the location of the containers, not the images. An image is the base file(s) to create a container.

Comment: @FelipeCorrea, Yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

It should be here:

```
C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\
```

Answer (score 1):

With Engine: `20.10.17(Windows 10)`,
I found my docker container at path: `\\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\containers`

You can see detail below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

(since so many answers are outdated and I don't have rep 50 to simply comment, duh)

Docker Desktop for Windows seems to have the files here:
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl

Probably better to export what you want to share instead with (OWASP10 webgoat example)

docker save -o c:\temp\mygoat.tar webgoat/goatandwolf

Which I suspect can then be picked up by another user using

docker load --input c:\temp\mygoat.tar

Comment: If you can't comment, you can click Edit to Suggest a change for improvement.

Comment: Above approach (directory correct as another user, save and load for container) confirmed as working.
Will test edit to suggest changes in the future. Ty, not using SO much anymore, probably had a "good" account 10 years ago.

Answer (score -1):

By default it is inside `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks` directory (.vhdx file).
It can be changed in Docker's settings > Advanced > Disk image location

Comment: This is outdated

Answer (score -1):

I am running on Windows 10 Home Version 2004 with Docker 19.03.8.  This has the new WSL back-end - in that configuration, launch a WSL prompt (Win-r then wsl to launch) and my image files are under /mnt/host/wsl/docker-desktop-data/data/docker

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
%USERPROFILE%/.docker/config.json
```