# Where are Docker volumes located when running WSL using Docker Desktop?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-desktop

I am running *Windows Subsystem Linux* (WSL) with Ubuntu as client OS under Windows 10. Now I installed *Docker Desktop* on the Windows host and enabled the WSL integration in the Docker settings. That works fine so far, I can access the Docker daemon running on the Windows host from my WSL Ubuntu client.

Now I am wondering where all the Docker volumes and other data is stored in this setup. Usually these are under `/var/lib/docker`, but it seems when using WSL this is not the case. When running `df -h` I can see the following Docker-related lines:

```
/dev/sdd        251G  3.1G  236G   2% /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/isocache
/dev/sdc        251G  120M  239G   1% /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/shared-sockets
/dev/loop0      244M  244M     0 100% /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools
```

So they are somewhere on the Windows host it seems.
... but where?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

When I create a volume named shared_data in docker, I can find it under

```
\\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes\shared_data\\_data
```

Comment: Yes, that's the path if you use Docker Desktop on WSL2 (Ubuntu), see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64418064/6075581

Comment: Search for this path in windows explorer when docker engine is active

Comment: Can we assume that the standard WSL warning of not editing WSL files through Windows File Explorer still holds for Docker containers?

Comment: Note, this is not the same path as /mnt/wsl ... inside WSL, this is only the path as accessed from the Windows 'host' file system

Comment: In Docker Desktop version 4.13 its at "\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\mnt\wsl\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes"

Answer (score 51):

You can find WSL2 volumes under a hidden network share. Open Windows Explorer, and type `\\wsl$` into the location bar. Hit enter, and it should display your WSL volumes, including the ones for Docker for Windows.

Comment: To follow onRohaq's answer...paste this into Windows Explorer to see the data volumes: \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes   PS. I am no Docker expert but this tip helped me greatly.

Comment: All I get inside that volumes folder is two files, `backingFsBlockDev` and `metadata.db`

Comment: @MattFletcher What path are you using?

Answer (score 24):

## Windows 10 + WSL2

I run docker-desktop on Windows 10 + WSL2. Just make sure you run the docker desktop, so the path would be accessible from a network.

I found my volume data under

```
\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes
```

[image]

Note that you need to have docker desktop running before you will be able to discover those network direcotories:

[image]

Comment: The only right and working answer in 2022..!

Comment: There is no such directory on docker community edition. Try `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes` as mentioned below.

Comment: Thanks. using docker v4.23.0, yours is the only one that work currently. However, i don't understand. I do this docker volume inspect abc,  the mountspoint show /var/lib/docker/volumes/abc/_data , but yet the actual location is  \\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes\abc\ _data.  The portion of the path before the volumes not the same....wonder why

Comment: Any idea how to get to \\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes\abc\ _data using the WSL command prompt

Comment: Did you try /mnt/c/.... ?

Comment: It's 2024 and I'm using Windows 11 and Docker v4.27.2. My Docker volumes is located here: `\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes\`

Answer (score 18):

If you are wondering where on the Windows host the docker volumes are located, for me they seem to be at:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\data\ext4.vhdx
```

and

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\distro\ext4.vhdx
```

presumably, these are `docker-desktop-data` and `docker-desktop` respectively.

In theory, these WSL2 instances can be re-located to an alternate drive to free disk space as per [this post](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4699#issuecomment-660104214); that is the standard method for exporting, unregistering, and re-importing an instance from a new location.  This process is also described [here](https://blog.iany.me/2020/06/move-wsl-to-another-drive/) (with regard to standard WSL instances).

(Caveat - I haven't yet done this with the docker WSL2 instances yet myself, only for Ubuntu using the method in the second link.)

Answer (score 13):

Most answers on this topic are about the location from the Windows side, I needed to access the container log files (the issue is the same as for volumes) **from my WSL distribution**, the Windows path `\\wsl$` was not an option.

The files could be found on Windows in `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\containers`.

From the WSL distribution, I could go to `/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data` but it was empty.

Finally found a solution [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/4176#discussioncomment-831817):

1. From Windows, create a disk for `docker-desktop-data`:

```
net use w: \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data
```

2. From your WSL distribution, mount it to `docker`:

```sh
sudo mkdir /mnt/docker
sudo mount -t drvfs w: /mnt/docker
```

Now you can get everything you want, in my case log files:

```sh
ls -l /mnt/docker/version-pack-data/community/docker/containers/

total 0
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 512 May 19 15:06 3f41ade0891c06725e828853524d73f185b415d035262f9c51d6b6e03654d505
```

Comment: If someone is looking for the volumes, these would then be located under /mnt/docker/data/docker/volumes

Comment: wow, thank you very much, this was really helpful. I used this to get my gpg files into the container in order to do signing of commits from within a dev container.

Answer (score 7):

[Docker Desktop's WSL2 feature](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl-tech-preview/) creates two new wsl2 containers `docker-desktop` and `docker-desktop-data`, which can be seen by the command `wsl -l -v`

```
NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-18.04           Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
```

This is where the docker daemon actually runs and where you can find the data you are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

The volumes in the wsl2 kernel are mapped as follows:

`docker run -ti -v host_dir:/app amazing-container` will get mapped to `/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/data/docker/volumes/host_dir/_data/`

The above is the **right** path, even though `docker volume inspect amazing-container` will tell you differently (`/var/lib/docker/volumes/`).

To conclude, the volumes are mapped to: `/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/data/docker/volumes/`

Comment: How can you query the docker server to return the right path?

Comment: @Carlin'tVeld replace `/var/lib/docker/volumes/` with `/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/data/docker/volumes/`

Comment: Well I would like to learn how to pull that data from the Docker server. In the meanwhile I found out that at my side the path is different: \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes\myvol\_data. Refer to https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/4176. Strangely when trying to reach out to his folder within wsl2 I find /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data being empty.

Comment: @Carlin'tVeld Same for me, I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61083772/where-are-docker-volumes-located-when-running-wsl-using-docker-desktop#answer-72307042) with a solution found in the GitHub discussion.

Comment: Why would the wsl developers point the mount path to a different location than what `docker volume inspect` outputs? Horrible.

Comment: @j7skov maybe for persistence and consolidation of how docker runs inside wsl and in windows

Answer (score 4):

If you are running Docker on Windows host, using Docker Desktop, you can access the volumes at `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes\` (search this path from windows explorer and make sure docker engine is running).

When running Docker desktop app, the app creates its own Linux VM or using WSL to run the docker container and the path `/var/lib/docker/volumes/` is from within that VM I think. The volumes are created as mountable `.vhdx` file at

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\distro\
```

but accessing this directly is tricky.

Ref: [Google how to access WSl files from Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/426749/how-to-access-your-linux-wsl-files-in-windows-10/)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, i install docker-desktop on wsl2, windows 10 home. i find my image files in

```
\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\overlay2
```

All image files are stored there, and have been seperated into several folders with long string names. When i look into every folder, i can find all the real image files in "diff" folders.
Although the terminal show the path "var/lib/docker", but the folder doesn't exsit and the actual files are not stored there. i think there is no error, the "var/lib/docker" is just linked or mapped to the real folder, kind like that.
In windows, we also use mklink to link two folders, it is similar, right?

Comment: Indeed, this is correct. The physical images and their layers are organized in this folder. But please note that they work together with /volumes folder as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can find volumes and others data when using docker with WSL under docker-desktop-data

[image: volume and other data in docker]

Comment: Mine didn't have host, but everything else is the same on my system. Once you get to the docker directory permissions are locked down. I did a `sudo ls volumes` to finally see my data

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 + WSL2, Docker Desktop v4.13.1, free service tier, 2022-11-03:
I found my volumes at `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes`

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 11 and WSL2 (Ubuntu 22.04.2) the path shown in File Explorer is:

```
\\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes\my-volume\_data
```

You can browse to it by first typing in `\\\wsl$` or `\\\wsl.localhost` on the search prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11 + WSL2

\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes\mivolumen

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave this here for other people looking for the path on the Linux distro used on WSL (Windows 11, Docker Desktop 4.20.1).

Given the Windows path:
`\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes` (or `\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes`)

It'll be found on the following path on the distro:
`/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data/community/docker/volumes` (requires sudo)