# Does volume mountpoint have any meaning in docker desktop on WSL 2?

Tags: docker, wsl-2

Following the Docker Desktop tutorial I created a volume for todo-db and I can see the inspect information is reporting a Mountpoint of /var/lib/docker/volumes/todo-db/_data.

```
{
    "CreatedAt": "2023-03-09T15:45:15Z",
    "Driver": "local",
    "Labels": {},
    "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/todo-db/_data",
    "Name": "todo-db",
    "Options": {},
    "Scope": "local"
}
```

After looking for hours I finally found
[Where are Docker volumes located when running WSL using Docker Desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61083772/where-are-docker-volumes-located-when-running-wsl-using-docker-desktop) and found it there, but the path where it's found (`\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes`) doesn't seem to remotely resemble the path indicated in Mountpoint. Does the Mountpoint have any meaning? Is that path valid in any context I can verify?

I've also reviewed [Locating data volumes in Docker Desktop (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43181654/locating-data-volumes-in-docker-desktop-windows) and it too identifies the location where volumes are located, but it doesn't resemble the mountpoint reported in the inspect output.