how & where Docker Image & its metadata are stored on Windows 10?
I want to see how Docker Image & its metadata are stored in Windows 10 (with Docker Desktop).
So, when I execute docker info in WSL 2 in Windows 10, it shows root directory as /var/lib/docker but when I go inside /var/lib/ folder in WSL 2, it doesn't show any folder name with docker. why? Although, it has docker-desktop folder which contains mount.data.
So, it's possible to navigate through folders in WSL 2 & see all the locations where Docker Image and its metadata are stored?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61083772/where-are-docker-volumes-located-when-running-wsl-using-docker-desktop

(The on-disk data isn't usually directly consumable.  The specific format images are stored in can change between Docker installations, and a given layer directory will only have some of the files that are in the final image.  It's usually better to use Docker APIs to interact with images and containers, though it's hard to directly see the filesystem.)
