# How to locate docker images in WSL?

Tags: docker, terminal, dockerfile, wsl-2, docker-image

#### I am running WSL and I want to find where the docker images are stored in my filesystem.

- I've tried `docker info` and it shows `Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker`
- but when I do `ls /var/lib/docker` it shows `ls: cannot access '/var/lib/docker/': No such file or directory`
- Tried finding some info and came across this [fcc blog](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/where-are-docker-images-stored-docker-container-paths-explained/) regarding Docker on Windows:

---

### [image: fcc blog on docker image]

- but mine contains only txt files and a tmp folder.

---

[image: DockerDesktop screenshot]

---

- I tried inspecting an image I've built and it shows: `

```
"GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/tm64pahi18wlse3ibs2uex6dm/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/s4jgik32xo1e9qoqie33bt6d7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/m9ea6j2mrehihllvnm1s51uyi/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1o1586gytwxyzhuap98m5a9v4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/437dfxzj5gmfrbs6f5a9pj0xt/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4d53adbcad7cc93f261de7f36303a7e1c54ae1cf1accb2768c881be550dd4e95/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/62106246a0f1977a89f193792c0f066a10bc8179e1406d1931cb8c8f15dc47f4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/28cf7a8fe3d1eab10f09a1056a7a36f88425c331cd0681b6cf1159156238cf4c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6fd3c82e02de85abceb47d0a58a06405c1cab0301c73a70939f507a3810fa540/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4d5eb280e3c8445439d9ee40ba3c066e6c11caf0a76f104e2795195c50ac8389/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9az4itvoy9m4jv669niircfar/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9az4itvoy9m4jv669niircfar/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9az4itvoy9m4jv669niircfar/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        }
```

- but doing `ls` gives the same `ls: cannot access '/var/lib/docker/': No such file or directory`

---

- The only place I can see anything that I can understand is using `docker images` and in Docker Desktop where I can see the size an image takes up.

---

- My OS info is below

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
```

Comment: [How to access /var/lib/docker in windows 10 docker desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60408574/how-to-access-var-lib-docker-in-windows-10-docker-desktop) asks a similar question; do the paths there work for you?  Even on native Linux there's very little you can usefully do with that content – images are stored in a fragmented and installation-specific manner – and I'd generally recommend ignoring the `/var/lib/docker` directory entirely.