# Is there a way to see container disk usage on Docker for Windows?

Tags: windows, docker

I'm curious if there's a way to see how much disk space a running Windows container is using in addition to the layers that are part of the container's image.  Basically, how much the container "grew" since it was created.

In Linux (Or Linux containers running in a HyperV), this would be `docker ps -s`, however that command isn't implemented on Windows containers.  I also tried `docker system df -v` but also, not implemented.  Perhaps there's a hacky way by looking at a certain directly on disk or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked on Windows 10 1809 running non-HyperV (process isolation) containers, I'm pretty sure its the same for Windows Server containers.

The data seems to be kept in:

```
C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\{ContainerId}
```

There's a direct reference to the folder in `docker inspect {Id}` under `GraphDriver\Data\dir`.

The folder contains file `sandbox.vhdx` which appears to be the "writable layer" of each container.

I wasn't able to open it and view the filesystem, but if I write some data inside the container I can force the file to grow:

```
  docker exec <Id> powershell get-childitem c:\ -recurse `> c:\windows\temp\test.txt
```

The layer persists when the container is stopped/restarted, and the folder is removed when the container is `rm`ed.

While researching I saw an [open PR in moby](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/39193) to improve cleanup of this folder.

Comment: Ooh this looks promising!  Wait a sec, are Moby PRs required to have a picture of a cute animal?  This needs to be a thing!

Comment: I am kinda curious why a brand new container starts out with a writable layer of around 132 megs..  Is that normal?  Maybe Docker is copying some stuff around for some perf reason, or maybe Windows starting up various services touches a whole bunch of files?

Comment: Startup file writes sounds plausible; starting a blank `nanoserver:1809` creates a 13mb file.

Comment: Yea I was trying a Windows Server Core image with IIS enabled, so probably a bunch more startup activity.  Either way, it seems like this is the answer.  Hope they fix the `ps -s` feature at some point!

Comment: Also you mentioned you were running on Windows 10 1809 running non-HyperV containers?  I though WIndows 10 _only_ supported Hyper-V?  I read it was some sort of licensing issue or something..

Comment: Oh looks like you can do it now!  Sweet!

Comment: Yes you can now use process isolation via Docker Desktop; I'm running actual DockerEE on 1809 (technically not licensed by Docker but I'm sure ok for dev/test), kudos to this guy: https://www.kauffmann.nl/2019/03/04/how-to-install-docker-on-windows-10-without-hyper-v/

Answer (score 1):

I'm using docker for windows (docker desktop 2.0.0.3) and `docker ps -s` is actually implemented.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND              CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES               SIZE
81acb264aa0f        httpd               "httpd-foreground"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        80/tcp              httpd               2B (virtual 132MB)
```

Docker for windows runs on a MobyLinuxVM. You can access the VM and the docker directories:

```
docker run --privileged -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jongallant/ubuntu-docker-client
root@8b58d2fbe186:/# docker run --net=host --ipc=host --uts=host --pid=host –it --security-opt=seccomp=unconfined --privileged --rm -v /:/host alpine /bin/sh
root@8b58d2fbe186:/# chroot /host
```

Now you can access the docker folders in `/var/lib/docker` as on linux and check the sizes.

Comment: Oops, guess I have to update my question!  This pertains to Windows containers, not Linux containers.  Sorry!