# Docker: Cannot delete intermediate images from a broken pull

Tags: image, docker, pull, pruning

There is a broken image which blocks further pulls. And I cannot remove or delete it

What I did:

```
- stopped all containers ("docker ps -a" shows empty list)
- cleaned everything with "docker system prune -a")
- "docker image ls -a" shows an empty list
```

When I pull something based on PHP7.3 I get this error:

```
$ sudo docker pull wordpress
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/wordpress
bc51dd8edc1b: Already exists 
a3224e2c3a89: Already exists 
be7a066df88f: Already exists 
bfdf741d72a9: Already exists 
a9e612a5f04c: Already exists 
c026d8d0e8cb: Already exists 
d94096c4941c: Already exists 
5a16031a7587: Already exists 
0cf1daf9efc0: Already exists 
b202acb13a6c: Already exists 
907001e30880: Already exists 
2e4b329c80b2: Already exists 
cd1ec92e7164: Already exists 
8cba435f5ca6: Already exists 
42d9ff86311d: Extracting [==================================================>]   16.7MB/16.7MB
4907cef4e3ab: Download complete 
d9efb2f24248: Download complete 
8301b0ae2103: Download complete 
a9e295ae3552: Download complete 
cd1a22f91cdc: Download complete 
f81677d558c1: Download complete 
failed to register layer: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/081694acd847bf622c20fa32b7cebad1ca46d4848cd49c336812fc03d60457c5/merged: too many levels of symbolic links
```

I am wondering about "already exists": How to delete them?? (I already tried prune -a ; see above)

I wish I could delete ALL(100%) images -> so I could start with fresh downloads.

(Background: the hardware had a memory bug. Perhaps that is the reason for having this error now. The hardware and disks are OK now.)

Comment: it might be that your docker service has some other problems and the `/var/lib/docker` remains "dirty". I'd try the following: `service docker stop ; cd /var/lib; mv docker docker.old; mkdir docker ; service docker start` and then repull the image

Comment: That will remove all 33 volumes as well. I would prefer to save them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to :

- Stop docker service
- Remove /var/lib/docker
- Start docker service

Comment: OK. That could work for the images. There are 33 Volumes "local". I would loose all the data in these volumes? I am not sure what is in there.

Comment: I dont like that way very much. It sounds a little bit like Win95: if it stops working just re-install it.

But I did it and it worked.

Comment: An explanation would help for what this answer does... but at least it works.

Comment: It works, but just keep this in mind when removing the "/var/lib/docker" : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46672001/is-it-safe-to-clean-docker-overlay2 :)

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me after I had symlinked /var/lib/docker

Answer (score 0):

For those who still depends on VirtualBox Docker Machine first SSH to VM:

```
docker-machine ssh
docker-machine ssh default
docker-machine ssh %NAME%
```

then stop service / delete Docker storage / start service inside the VM:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/docker stop
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
sudo /etc/init.d/docker start
```

My Docker Machive was corrupted after `no space left on device` in Windows...

Note that following didn't help:

```
docker container prune
docker image prune --all --force
```