# How to fix docker container after deleting overlay2 folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Folder `docker/overlay2` was deleted, and now all my containers fall with error `stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/***: no such file or directory`
Is there any way to fix this without losing all container data?

Answer (score 8):

Solution

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

Comment: Note this wipes all Docker image and container content, ok if that's what you want to do but might not be subtle enough for some use cases.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any way to fix this without losing all container data?

No, you've already lost your container data. All you have left now are pointers to where the data used to be. This is why I strongly [recommend against deleting files from within this folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46672068/596285) unless you plan to completely reset docker to an empty state. At this point, the cleanest thing to do is shutdown the docker engine, delete the rest of the files and directories from `/var/lib/docker`, and restart. If you have data in named volumes, you may wish to first save that folder.

Comment: This is incorrect. The actual data is stored in volumes. Who knows what "overlay2" does. See my answer for a solution.

Comment: @Akaisteph7 "If you have data in named volumes, you may wish to first save that folder." To get an idea of what's stored in overlay2, inspect an image or container, and see where the graph driver stores the filesystem layers. All of the images and changes from the read/write container layer have been lost when overlay2 is deleted.

Comment: I am pretty sure the OP meant actual DB data by "container data" and not image/layer data. The latter can easily be recreated while the former cannot.

Comment: Something I've learned the hard way is that is not a safe assumption. There are quite a few people that treat containers as pets even though they shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I present to you the incantation to solve your problems:

```
docker system prune --all
sudo rm -r /var/lib/docker/overlay2/
systemctl restart docker
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
docker compose down && docker compose build --progress plain --no-cache && docker compose up
```

Be advised that the first line will prompt you to delete all existing images, containers not in use, and build cache. These are easily recreated however (in the last step) and no database data will be lost.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77753922/8285811) for a similar Q&A with more alternatives.

Comment: OP has already deleted overlay2 and is asking how to preserve the container data. This appears to give directions on how to delete everything and recreate all of the containers assuming they were deployed with compose.

Comment: @BMitch You can skip the second line if already deleted, makes no difference. This does delete existing containers and images, which you have to accept, but I'll add a note about that.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problems, and I restart Jenkins Agents in my case
=> Problem solved

I think that may be build cache problems.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35719738)

Comment: @AztecCodes how is this not an answer?

Comment: @starball I believe that there is nothing in OPs question that indicates this has anything to do with Jenkins.

Comment: @Tschösi good point. I think these cases are debatable where to delete or not though... related: I sometimes see positively scored answers about VS Code on VS questions, and vice versa.