# Docker /var/lib/docker/overlay2/<id>/merged: no such file or directory

Tags: docker

I am getting following error and couldn't find any solution.

```
#9 [builder 3/5] COPY . /app
#9 sha256:deb3e9c3d0d018c2253369e84f48bc653a4796eebadd10de1a2bb60b4954e239
#9 ERROR: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/93eywfuy5gffv03b5zcpgetvq/merged: no such file or directory
------
 > [builder 3/5] COPY . /app:
------
error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/93eywfuy5gffv03b5zcpgetvq/merged: no such file or directory
```

Tried to clean up images, containers via following docker commands nothing help:

```
docker system prune -af
docker builder prune
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)

# Tried to pull images without caches also failed
docker build --pull --no-cache -t "my-app" .
```

System detail: macOs Monterey

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65655199/596285

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix this;

- Close Docker
- Remove containers manually

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker
```

- Start docker and it will magically work!

***update: 14/09/2023***

Sometimes only cleaning & purging via Docker dashboard also helps (this screen opens when you click 'bug' icon at the top right of the screen):

[image: Docker purging data]

Comment: Cannot find this location on ubuntu server

Comment: Above one for a macOs machine, please follow other comments for kubuntu etc

Answer (score 8):

the fix is to edit /etc/docker/daemon.json file and add below content to it:

```
{ "storage-driver": "devicemapper" }
```

Reload the systemctl daemon:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

And restart docker service:

```
systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: It is on macOs :)

Comment: I have updated the detail.

Comment: Worked on Kubuntu

Comment: This storage-driver is deprecated and will be removed v25

Answer (score 8):

Such scenarios can be solved by cleaning unused containers of docker.

Run prune command to clear:

docker system prune -a

After this :: restart docker

Comment: The only that worked for me. Thanks! I think I caused the the original problem by manually deleting big files inside the docker directory when my computer was running low on storage.

Answer (score 1):

Man this is an [old and persistent issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1396) with docker. Granted, it is often caused by people modifying a folder they aren't supposed to but that's usually because docker doesn't always properly clean up after itself.

At this point, I have an incantation that I go through each time I inevitably have to delete the content of "overlay2" as it starts hogging over 20GB of space as running `prune` does nothing to it. Here it is:

```
docker system prune --all
sudo rm -r /var/lib/docker/overlay2/
sudo rm -r /var/lib/docker/image
sudo rm -r /var/lib/docker/devicemapper
sudo systemctl restart docker
# DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0  # Optional - has been helpful
docker compose down && docker compose --progress plain build --no-cache && docker compose up
```

There seems to be lots of ways docker caches things internally so a lot needs to be temporarily deleted or disabled for this to work, but not always. It really depends on your particular setup but the above should help.

Answer (score 0):

After removing all docker files, from `/var/lib/docker` I had similar error.

So, had to remove the docker packages first.

`sudo dnf remove docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce docker-ce-cli docker-compose-plugin`

Then to remove volumes

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker /etc/docker
sudo rm /etc/apparmor.d/docker
sudo groupdel docker
sudo rm -rf /var/run/docker.sock
```

Also remove `~/.docker` directory from `~` home.