# Accidentally removed docker images

Tags: docker

I was running into disk space issues due to the /var/lib/docker/overlay2 directory. I was clever enough to remove some images that had been created a while ago, figuring that would be harmless.

It wasn't, and this was not a smart thing to do.

Nevertheless, here we are, and when I try to perform a docker build for my project now, I run into the following error:

```
error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/<id>/merged: no such file or directory
```

I would very much appreciate some help on how to fix this. Please let me know if you need further information or clarification, I don't work with docker a whole lot as you might surmise from the question.

Comment: Have you tried to restart docker ?

Comment: If restarting Docker doesn't help, I would just stop docker, `rm -rf /var/lib/docker/overlay2`, and then start docker. In general, you should only interact with docker through the API -- use `docker image rm` to delete images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker /var/lib/docker/overlay2/<id>/merged: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71314384/docker-var-lib-docker-overlay2-id-merged-no-such-file-or-directory)