# OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"chmod\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

My dockerfile was working fine earlier but after deleting files inside overlay directory problem started the same code is working on different server where overlay is untouched ,

1. I restarted docker system and daemon and did docker system prune but no use .
2. Added bash after the command in dockerfile same issue .
   Please don't hesitate to reply even if its a small suggestion. TQ

Comment: Please post your full Dockerfile and how you're running it, if it might relevant. Thanks!

Comment: If you edited files directly inside the `/var/lib/docker` space you're not going to have reproducible results.  I'd recommend stopping Docker, deleting the entire `/var/lib/docker` tree, and rebuilding any local images you have.

Comment: You've corrupted docker beyond repair. As David mentions, you now need to delete the rest to reset docker to an empty state and start over. For more details, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46672068/596285