# How to find which docker images that uses a specific overlay directory

Tags: docker

Struggling with the lacking documentation at $DAY_JOB, I have figured out that I need to use one of our docker images that contain a specific *.so file. Let's call it "libimportant.so".

A search with `find` reveals that the file exists in a local docker layer in my dev environment:

```bash
$ sudo find / -name libimportant.so 2>/dev/null
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/fedc8afc375f5bf02c74542b5d3a2621fcfd522875dff06bbb63fff6d1251234/diff/usr/lib64/libimportant.so
```

I have over 200 docker images locally (according to `docker image ls | wc -l`).

**Question:** How do I figure out which docker image (or docker images) that are using this docker layer?

**NOTE:** The environment currently has no containers running. This is a question about images, not containers.

I tried creating a container for each image, export the files, and search for the file in question. But this solution seems to take forever to run. It never run to completion.

```bash
$ docker image ls -qa | while read -r _hash; do _container="$(docker create "$_hash")"; docker container export "$_container" | tar t | grep -q 'libimportant.so' && echo "$_hash"; docker container rm "$_container" >/dev/null; done
^C
$
```

I also tried to list the GraphDriver data for each image, and grep for the overlay hash. But that didn't find any matches.

```bash
$ docker image ls -qa | while read -r imageid; do docker image inspect --format '{{json .GraphDriver.Data}}' "$imageid" | grep -q 'fedc8afc375f5bf02c74542b5d3a2621fcfd522875dff06bbb63fff6d1251234' && echo "$imageid"; done
$
```

docker version

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.13
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        4484c46d9d
 Built:             Wed Sep 16 17:02:52 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
```

**POST EDIT**

The reason I could not find the image was because my `/etc/docker/daemon.json` had reconfigured "data-root" from `/var/lib/docker` to another directory.

Therefore the layers in `/var/lib/docker/overlay2` was not used by any image listed with `docker image ls`.

After correcting this, searching the GraphDriver.Data for each image actually worked.

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Comment: My bad. I found many similar docker questions on SO and thought it was the right place.

Comment: This question includes answers about inspecting images: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67607874/596285

Comment: Link stackoverflow.com/q/67607874/596285 includes how to inspect one specific image. I can not see an answer on how to search all images for a specific overlay directory.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my post edit, when I first tried to figure this out dockerd was using the wrong data-root.

Here is my solution using GraphDriver that worked for me, pretty printed:

```bash
layer_id="your_hash"

docker image ls -qa \
  | while read -r imageid; do
      docker image inspect --format '{{json .GraphDriver.Data}}' "$imageid" \
        | grep -q "$layer_id" && echo "$imageid"
    done
```