# Mapping docker storage layer directory to docker image

Tags: docker, shell

I have the following directories representing the layers of my docker images:

```
root@castelli:~# ls /var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes/| tail
d4c8f01c9af5b2c49d4b1e08c8a4b1fe78fa0e3caed8bd5a186dea7d01336c87
d6f300048f2777bf140c46e8d0775ad6f6fab9e952914f77a528c3be07b80827
db0314c58a9b90f20cc33a8c0524680ca2b673ed5fc728852a161ba14bac7d1b
e46a4f0f856f5582b1ec9079855c577774f7316b9bc6a78bae1c0418c573d463
e64bc04a30e985af22487da53110c3cc8acee2be6dc4e3b76c9a708da0a16418
f317340a19ca4062294a120523e1ac002e15b711fa067660f79d3af86ce6cd65
f8ad17972f3845bfffedf0b0a1ebfa9150c8e299dea1f3a718b833d016f18a2d
f95f0d7049eeaab55be02bed66867bc800de65b68977cd00c69209cc7ec0edc5
f9dc9e05ce8f5e2a611a4ede18c29c34df9fd9c005d86f27738a2fd31f9f4d00
faaad1d6f3a7197c7715e8c1c71df20be181d0f061b93b382e7f4ca592c03c02
```

I would like to know to which image the layer ID the `d6f300048f2777bf140c46e8d0775ad6f6fab9e952914f77a528c3be07b80827` directory corresponds to.

I tried listing all the images on my system and the ids of their layers like so:

```
root@castelli:~# for i in $(docker images | awk '{print $1}'); do echo $i; docker image inspect --format "{{json .RootFS.Layers}}" $i ; done
[...]
python
["sha256:ff61a9b258e5be019eb30e2ea80b8cefaafb27360a154e5ec0e50f7b9a9cc068","sha256:43ba18a5eaf87c0a4c4bf4ea6fc04d26774e8302bc20dd9b2a5e4023cb75c087","sha256:6aa872026017a6174385a71ce57d72500b5acbac1e1ec168880d0028ce773ae9","sha256:b485c6cd33a6678b17655f6ef5fbde009a366e207c04d59535daa61dd397bc6d","sha256:b2e5b1eee1926981ddfee0a93100625fbc78b12fb20a708dcbaf5ac805b38ae3","sha256:9ec39c52d830103366d42cf47f9de44bbbba4cf8a5cd84aeb4bd865f45c58c9e","sha256:6373bafd92eacd88b6a3d8b49d47c2c68b6c727b991304a80a25fe995b4d0f1d","sha256:619f433131412bedc4441ce95baf1b3f1ac760ef32a12e164e5a3ca6e061fa3b"]
registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/python-39
["sha256:efa8b1bea25f2f12563212d283f99066f6f871e27a69c0fbd571938a3c587421","sha256:136a80a3696f7ad61b9704b8ef3a6848916347d6c6cd32308058fef2780e3bc1","sha256:3a85d70d7e2d80c6eb6eaaccf1cb44d56a450dfc7f0ab5aae351cc6d08ad72bc","sha256:41a15a0129b604c021367c9817f7226ae9abfddc20db27a2c00f34a2c74813db"]
registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal
["sha256:969795712c492f0c43031ce89dfb3d6ca2c08221fc28fb4479c7e0a370af7342"]
```

Except, in the output of the latter command, I cannot find the id from above.  I have been browsing around the docker documentation and found some information about about the [overlay2 storage driver](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/):

> Each of these layers is stored in its own directory inside the Docker host's local storage area. To examine the layers on the filesystem, list the contents of /var/lib/docker/. This example uses the overlay2 storage driver:
>
> ```
> ls /var/lib/docker/overlay2
> 16802227a96c24dcbeab5b37821e2b67a9f921749cd9a2e386d5a6d5bc6fc6d3
> 377d73dbb466e0bc7c9ee23166771b35ebdbe02ef17753d79fd3571d4ce659d7
> 3f02d96212b03e3383160d31d7c6aeca750d2d8a1879965b89fe8146594c453d
> ec1ec45792908e90484f7e629330666e7eee599f08729c93890a7205a6ba35f5
> l
> ```
>
> The directory names don't correspond to the layer IDs.

I assume the holds true for the btrfs storage driver, which would also explain why my attempt above fails.

So again my question, how do I figure out the layer ID the `d6f300048f2777bf140c46e8d0775ad6f6fab9e952914f77a528c3be07b80827` directory corresponds to.

Comment: This post for overlay2 may be useful https://stackoverflow.com/q/67607874/596285

Comment: @BMitch, thanks for your comment, it got me into the right direction and that question does help in answering that problem for the overlay2 storage subsystem, but unfortunately, not the btrfs storage subsystem, which may not implement that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer to the general problem based on the question referred to by @BMitch.

If you have a docker system that uses the `overlay2` storage subsystem, all you have to do is look at the `GraphDriver` section when running `docker inspect $image_name`:

```
"GraphDriver": {
    "Data": {
        "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d6602c22cad0b9ff4596431f860beb4b3e5c67647d7aadc82a83f11ea6bf0119/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6b71e232ea5de31b44977252f6bc59fc80d97dc859566fbfa40fedef84964940/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/837ee76761d92cce3726168fa0ab0e0fe4258722d6309271ff574f318c320387/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/aa240b5ee87f8f900e450c8882e5e48cce6c87b04df5160a5ec16335ab2b65da/diff",
        "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/723c125a6f8a583e176a665342bc9bd19dbe59d1f60324895f337bfc17cb51f0/merged",
        "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/723c125a6f8a583e176a665342bc9bd19dbe59d1f60324895f337bfc17cb51f0/diff",
        "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/723c125a6f8a583e176a665342bc9bd19dbe59d1f60324895f337bfc17cb51f0/work"
    },
    "Name": "overlay2"
},
```

This seems to be all the information necessary.  There is one directory per layer.  To get the data in a more parse-able form, just do the following instead:

```
~# docker inspect python:3.8-slim-buster --format '{{.GraphDriver.Data.LowerDir }}'
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d6602c22cad0b9ff4596431f860beb4b3e5c67647d7aadc82a83f11ea6bf0119/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6b71e232ea5de31b44977252f6bc59fc80d97dc859566fbfa40fedef84964940/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/837ee76761d92cce3726168fa0ab0e0fe4258722d6309271ff574f318c320387/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/aa240b5ee87f8f900e450c8882e5e48cce6c87b04df5160a5ec16335ab2b65da/diff
~# docker inspect python:3.8-slim-buster --format '{{.GraphDriver.Data.WorkDir }}'
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/723c125a6f8a583e176a665342bc9bd19dbe59d1f60324895f337bfc17cb51f0/work
```

However, the system where I need to have my question answered uses the `btrfs` storage subsystem and for that the "GraphDriver" section only produces:

```
"GraphDriver": {
    "Data": null,
    "Name": "btrfs"
},
```

Maybe this is intentional, maybe not implemented, maybe there is another workaround.  This is only speculation, should you know, please extend.  Thanks!