# Is it safe to delete files in /mnt/docker/overlay2?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I am facing space issue in server due to docker overlay2 folder.It is taking space around 72GB.Many applications are running in this docker.Can I delete files which is in overlay2 folder?If I delete these files from overlay2 folder, any issues will occur in running containers? Please clarify. I have attached snapshot for reference.

[image: Docker Size]

Comment: This is off-topic.  It is not a programming question.

Comment: It's better to run `docker system prune -af` so that let docker deletes everything unused

Comment: ok.If I delete these files,will it impact running containers?

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered: [Is it safe to clean docker/overlay2/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46672001/is-it-safe-to-clean-docker-overlay2)

If docker uses a huge amount of space I recommend the following command:

> docker system prune --volumes

See
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56147993/4471199

Use with caution!

> docker system prune --help

may help