# Error response from daemon: stat /var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes/[...]: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, btrfs

I manually deleted a docker managed subvolumes

```
btrfs subvolume delete /var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes/<subvolume id>
```

but when I try to recreate it gives me this error that I'm not able to solve without nuclearize the docker installation

```
Error response from daemon: stat /var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes/<subvolume id>: no such file or directory
```

already tried to `stop`/`rm -f` the container, `docker system prune -f` and `systemctl restart docker.service` to no avail

Comment: You usually shouldn't manually modify anything in `/var/lib/docker` at all.  If you've corrupted that tree, it usually works to stop the Docker daemon, delete all of `/var/lib/docker` and restart the daemon; you'll have to rebuild/re-pull any images you had locally and recreate containers and named volumes.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying me that. What brought me to delete the subvolumes was an uncorrectable btrfs error as a result of a device scrub. After locating the subvolumes that had the corrupted file in its directory tree I deleted it: there's a way to safely remove the subvolume through docker console?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46672001/is-it-safe-to-clean-docker-overlay2/

Answer (score 18):

I also ended up with the error after deleting btrfs subvolumes myself (the bug that subvolumes are not freed by `docker system prune` still exists).

To recover, you have to delete `/var/lib/docker` as well:

```
systemctl stop docker
rm -rf /var/lib/docker
systemctl start docker
```

Comment: amazing, i was in a really weird state with a Docker installation on Arch / Manjaro after a timeshift restore. Wiping this fixed it all!

Answer (score 4):

well , i encountered same issue with docker on fedora which uses btrfs by default , Deleting the **/var/lib/docker** directory would remove all Docker data, including images, containers, volumes, and other configuration files.

Doing so will essentially reset Docker to a clean state, as if you've just installed Docker for the first time.

However, deleting the **/var/lib/docker** directory will lead to **data loss**.

All data related to Docker, such as running containers, images, and volumes, will be permanently lost. If you have important data stored within Docker containers or volumes, ***it will be gone after deleting this directory***.

removing images, and only **btrfs** directory in path **/var/lib/docker/btrfs** will fix the issue and no need to **docker system prune** or deleting the hole docker directory

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
docker rmi $(docker images -aq)
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/btrfs
sudo systemctl start docker
```

this is a much faster and safer fix to this issue 
note that deleting btrfs directory may take a while since it may has too many files

Answer (score 0):

I want to add one more command to [@Neo Mn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4605730/neo-mn)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76804670/11391913)

```
# rm -rf /var/lib/docker/image/btrfs
```

Without removing `/var/lib/docker/image/btrfs` directory, docker keep complaining about `Error response from daemon: stat /var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes/<somehash>: no such file or directory` and allowing me to start containers.