# Docker 'overlay' takes too much size - how to debug?

Tags: docker, centos

running df -h I get:

```
overlay          79G   70G  5.8G  93% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/a7bcb73019b20505a640593453aee3578647e027ccf90a607ad1806a9b25edd4/merged
```

Any idea how I can check why it takes so much space?

Answer (score 2):

An overlay filesystem, like a bind mount, doesn't use any disk space itself. What's reported is the disk space of the underlying filesystem. In this case, if you run `df /var/lib/docker` you'll see the same disk space allocated to that underlying filesystem, and you can review what is used on that mount.

If the issue is docker, then `docker system prune` would be a first step. If that doesn't help and you see significant usage from the /var/lib/docker folder you want to clean, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46672068/596285) for additional suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I come a bit late, but this question is a recurring one, and I think this is lacking a diagnose step.

As @bmitch says, first check the size of `/var/lib/docker`.

If docker is the problem, then run: `docker system df`. An example of output:

```
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          14        4         5.734GB   3.299GB (57%)
Containers      4         4         2.203MB   0B (0%)
Local Volumes   242       2         15.26GB   14.66GB (96%)
Build Cache     425       0         64.32GB   64.32GB
```

With that, you can cleary see what is taking space, and clean selectively.

In some cases (mine), the build cache is the problem. You can safely delete it with `docker builder prune`. The usual options for `prune` can apply (`--all`, `--filter`).

For images, volumes, use the classical `prune` commands.